Meaning of "the bulge" in "I wondered what the bulge in her coat pocket was."
The following example sentence is found in Cambridge Dictionary:

I wondered what the bulge in her coat pocket was.

The word "bulge" in this sentence has the following meaning:

a curved shape sticking out from the surface of something

In this sense, the sentence above can be interpreted as:

I wondered what the shape sticking out from her coat pocket was.

But in this interpretation, it becomes unsound because the speaker already knew how the shape was.
How should the sentence be interpreted correctly in this case?

Not 'the shape sticking out from her coat pocket' but 'something in her pocket causing the fabric of the coat to bulge out'. The speaker doesn't know what that 'something' is!

To clarify: "sticking out from the surface" can be understood as "causing a part of the surface to stick out, compared to what's around it."

it says I wondered what was in her coat pocket

To ask 'what a bulge is' is not to request a definition of the word 'bulge'. It is to ask to be told what is causing the bulge. It might be an apple, a gun, a baby, anything.
